# Is exposing my DTO to the view considered incorrect?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

This question has been round my head the last weeks or months, and I don't really know what's the best solution.

With the MVVM patter we use the View Models to expose data to a View.
For example, if I want to show to a user the details of a product I will create certain propeties inside the View Model and populate them. Then through bindings, the view will be able to get the data from those properties. Something like this:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Prodcut Name:" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProductName}" />

    <TextBlock Text="Price:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Price}"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Added Date:"  FontWeight="Bold" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In the view model I will retrieve the data that I want to display. I will get this data like a Product DTO, which will have the needed properties in the view.

```
 this.productDTO = getData();
```

So my question is, can we bind directy from the view model to the dto?
View Model:

```
    private ProductDTO product;

    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return this.product.Name; }
        set { this.product.Name = value; }
    }

    public string Price
    {
        get { return this.product.Price; }
        set { this.product.Price = value; }
    }
```

I have the idea that exposing the DTO is not a good thing.. 
but if It will save me from having to map all the properties from the DTO to the view model..

Comment: I think the best way to interject code between a model not designed for MVVM and the View is to use T4 templates to automatically generate custom type descriptors.  [This is a good starting place](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/08/declarative-dependency-property-definition-with-t4-dte/) which describes how to easily create dependency properties.  I reworked it to create custom type descriptors, which aren't that hard to code.  VS2011 has some super-sweet stuff in the compiler to make this even easier; check out the talk Anders gave at Build for more info.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not need to 'shape' your DTO in order to bind your view, there is absolutely nothing wrong with exposing your DTO directly to your view. You can always introduce a view model at some point in the future if required.

You can also use patterns like the mini-ViewModel (which [I describe on my blog](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/08/the-mini-viewmodel-pattern/)) to add localised View Models to shape parts of your model.

Wrapping your DTO in a view model as you have done, adds code that does not provide any benefit. It increases the size of your code-base and the risk of bugs.

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) - Keep it simple!

Comment: While I agree, you should remember that it's considered bad OOP to expose the data objects to the view, as you in that way, possible expose *more properties than necessary*.

Answer (score 5):

```
private ProductDTO product;

public string ProductName
{
    get { return this.product.Name; }
    set { this.product.Name = value; }
}
```

the only problem i can see is that, when your Name property of your dto changed its not simply reflected in your UI. so i would prefer this:

```
public ProductDTO Product {...}

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Product.Name}" />
```

this of course requires that your DTO implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: +1 for making aware of the problem with INPC. Normally data entities wouldn't implement INPC, and such it would be necessary to wrap it in the viewmodel.

Comment: but if I do this the whole DTO will be exposed to the view. If we create a view that is binding textboxes to properties that we dont want to change (ie the ID of the product). A user could alter our DTO. This could be very risky if we are doing a Save operation afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Technically both ways are possible, however a DTO typically is not meant for viewing and thus will probably not fire any change notification events. You'll have to either code that into your DTO or risk possible UI synchronization issues. I would advise against "enriching" your DTOs in such a way.

From an architecture standpoint DTO object should be cheap and small objects. They don't require a lot of effort to instantiate or destroy and you shouldn't pass them very far up your call stack let alone let them remain in memory for very long. In general they're meant to be data capsules and they're purpose is only to bring the data from A to B. ViewModels on the other hand have behavior and implement a richer set of interfaces. The only thing they have in common with DTOs is that they also have data properties.

So, in your case I'd advise not to keep the DTO in your view model as a private member, but set the view models properties upon retrieving the DTO and then forget about the DTO again. As a general advise, don't let your DTOs lifetime extend very far past the method with the service call.

Comment: I'm doing that thing that you are suggesting at the moment. But it is kind of annoying.. when i get the data i have to map the dto to the view model. And when I want to save it the opposite. I feel like I am writing code that I shouldnt, plus it's very easy to forget to map one of the properties.

Comment: If you want to save on tedious coding tasks you could look into domain driven design and write a model that allows you to auto-generate a lot of the code. For example, I took the Entity Framework edmx model as my domain model and wrote several T4 templates that will generate a lot of code for me: The DTOs, the mapping between Entities and DTOs, my client side business objects, their interfaces and the mapping between DTOs and business objects. I got this idea from [Samuel Meacham](http://samscode.com/index.php/2010/06/entity-framework-v4-end-to-end-application-strategy-part-1-intro/).